# how to setup a range to reach an answer along comparing through if condition in cpp

Tags: c++, function, range

i am writing code which will take some 2 values from user and then according to those 2 values we have to find root of a function. as we cannot go for unlimited itreations to find the exact 0 answer, i have specified a range for only **0.00(any digits after first 2 zeros)** answer for iterations to reach. but i cannot resolve how to setup that range in if condition. below is my work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int x[100], iteration = 0;
double recents1, recents2;


double function(int x) {
    return (x * x * x) - (9 * x) + 1;
}

double formula(int n) {
    double X, X2;
    X = ((x[n - 1] * function(x[n])) - (x[n] * function(x[n - 1])));
    X2 = X / (function(x[n]) - function(x[n - 1]));
    x[n + 1] = X2;
    return function(X2);
}

double falsePosition(int x1,int x2) {
    x[0] = x1; x[1] = x2; recents1 = function(x1); recents2 = function(x2);
    int i;
    double funVal=1;
    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        if (funVal != 0.00)
        {
            funVal = formula(i);
        }
        else {
            cout << "the root has been found";
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    int x1, x2;
    cout << "enter value of x1 : "; cin >> x1;
    cout << "enter value of x2 : "; cin >> x2;
    falsePosition(x1, x2);

    return 0;}
```

**funVal** variable is set up for limit in function **falsePosition**. please if any person can help me figure out how can i set up range of my own desire to be compared and get the final result. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The floating number cannot be precisely represented. Thus to check a double variable, you'd better check it within a range.

For example: instead of `if (funVal != 0.00)`, uses `if (funVal < 1e-6)` or other dedicated precidicetion instead.

Here is a demo with the full code

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
int main(){
    double val = 5.0;
    double const TARGET = 0.618033988;
    double const DELTA = 1e-6;
    int i = 0;
    while ( abs(val - TARGET) > DELTA ) {
        val = 1 / (1 + val);
        if (++i > 1000000) exit(1);
    }
    std::cout<<"after "<< i << " iterations get " << val<< std::endl;
}
```

- To compile and run

  ```
  g++ demo.cpp -Wall -o demo.out
  ./demo.out
  ```
- Output

  ```
  after 15 iterations get 0.618033
  ```

You can change `DELTA` to see the difference.